# What the difference between initialization on declaration and initialization in a next step?

Tags: c, initialization

I need to initialize a variable and test its value. 
What is the most efficient way to do this?

```
char *key = get_key(item);
if (key != NULL) { // do something }
```

OR

```
char *key; 
if (key = get_key(item)) { // do something }
```

Do side effects produce some advantage or not? 
Thanks!

Comment: In first place, the second snippet is not initialization. It's an assignment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ah, good ol' "most efficient way"... **No. NOPE. Forget efficiency.**

*Even if there was a difference,* this would very likely be premature optimization. But in this particular case, the only difference is in terminology (your second example is not, technically, initialization but an assignment expression), and your compiler will almost certainly generate the very same assembler out of the two pieces of code.

Answer (score 2):

In your simple program, the question to ask is: will you reuse the assignment? The cost of the assignment will be one memory store. If not used at all, then I would just not add the cost of the store. The compiler is probably doing that anyways, but doesn't hurt to help it :-)

If you do intend to reuse key, then I personally prefer not doing it inside the if() not in the declaration step for readability. So, I would do the second way, but keep the assignment out of the if().

Answer (score 0):

For your specific example, there is likely no difference.  Build both and compare the generated code to check.

Answer (score 0):

A standalone declaration (`char *key;`) produces no code at all, so most likely both code fragments will result in the same generated code, but arguably the first fragment is slightly easier to read.

Answer (score 0):

Ask yourself if efficiency is important.  (answer: highly unlikely)

Go for readability.   With that in mind doing an assignment inside an if condition is questionable, so I would strongly prefer the first version.

Answer (score 0):

Both code snippets are equivalent in behavior.

I personally don't like the second one as side-effects in the controlling expression of an `if` statement tend to make the code less readable and particularly when the side-effect is made with an assignment. This is by the way one of the reason (the tendency to make errors) why a language like Python forbids the use of the assignment operator in the controlling expression of the `if` statement.

This being said, I also don't like side-effects at initialization time (the function call in the declaration in the first code snippet).